# MonkeyTalk: Screen loading time, completion time/reaction time measurements?

Tags: performance-testing, latency, monkeytalk, time-measurement

Can latency measurements like  screen loading time, completion time/reaction time/response time of any operation(like opening a URL, tapping on a button, deleting a message, navigating to the next screen) be done using MonkeyTalk?

If it cannot be done using MonkeyTalk, are there any other open-source tools which will be helpful in this regard?

Your help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MonkeyTalk has modifiers such as `thinktime` and `timeout` to wait until a component is visible to continue.

See [here](http://gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/understanding-monkeytalk-commands/modifiers/thinktime) and [here](http://gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/understanding-monkeytalk-commands/modifiers/timeout) for the documentation on those.